# How can I output unique values in postgreSQL? (without distinct)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got some table with information about people(id, name, surname). My table contains repeated surnames and I want to select count of surnames excluding repetitions. I know how to do this with `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SURNAME) FROM PEOPLE;
```

But how to do it differently? I'm a beginner at sql, so please help me!

Comment: What exactly is the output you want? Are you looking for a simple group by? `select surname, count(*) from people group by surname;`

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot;:)

Answer (score 0):

Your method is the right way to do it.  You could also use a subquery:

```
select count(surname)
from (select distinct surname from people) s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is with:

```
SELECT count(*) from (select surname FROM PEOPLE group by 1) foo;
```

Note that this might give a slightly different answer, as it counts NULL surnames (if any) one time while `count(DISTINCT...)` will not count such surnames at all.  Also, this can be faster as it may make use of parallelization and hash aggregation, while `count(DISTINCT...)` will not do so.